# How Can I Solve These 3 Coupled PDEs in Python?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, fourier-transform, python

I need to simulate the following system of equations in python:
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}=-I S-\beta A S+\rho_{d} I+\rho_{c} A-\left(\alpha_{d}+\alpha_{c}\right) S + d_s \frac{\partial ^2S}{\partial x^2}\\
&\frac{\partial I}{\partial t}=I S-\rho_{d} I+\alpha_{d} S-\sigma_{d c} I+\sigma_{c d} A +d_I\frac{\partial ^2 I}{\partial x^2}\\
&\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}=\beta A S-\rho_{c} A+\alpha_{c} S+\sigma_{d c} I-\sigma_{c d} A + d_A \frac{\partial ^2 A}{\partial x^2}
\end{align*}

Where I can chose the parameter values.

I have seen that perhaps I could take the Fourier transform of the equations and try to create ODE's. However, I don't know how to Fourier transform the non-linear terms like $-\beta AS$?

To clarify, I would like to solve these numerically in Python:)

Thank you, Rik.

Comment: No need to sign your posts - we see who you are. Also, do you know any numerical schemes? Finite element, finite difference, ...?

Comment: The non-linear terms are products. When Fourier transformed these become convolutions, which are worse to handle than products. Therefore I do not believe in taking the Fourier transform of the equations.

Comment: @SeanRoberson thanks for the reply. I am not familiar with any numerical methods, besides at a surface level. But I am happy to learn one if needs be. My ultimate goal is just to implement the code in Python, I am less concerned with understanding the process (although I guess that may be needed).

Comment: @md2perpe Okay thank you

Comment: I would suggest using the [Dedalus code](https://dedalus-project.org/).